# GCD algorithms for a large integers

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, biginteger, greatest-common-divisor, computation

I'm studying fast (sub-quadratic) GCD computation algorithms and looking for any details of them. I would like to have a look at their implementation, to get a chance to understand them better.

The Euclid GCD and Binary GCD algorithms (with quadratic running times) are obviously quite simple and I have no problems with them.

The algorithms that I'm looking for are:
• Lehmer GCD algorithm,
• Accelerated GCD algorithm,
• k-ary algorithm,
• Knuth-Schönhage with FFT.

All of them are very difficult for me to understand. Can anyone please share the code (ideally in C++) with the implementation of any algorithm from the list or share any hints of how to implement them? I would appreciate any information, clues, or advice.

I could not find any information whatsoever, about the *accelerated GCD* algorithm. I've seen it was sometimes referred to as the most effective and fast gcd computation method on the medium inputs (~1000 bits).

I'm most interested in having a working implementation of Lehmer GCD algorithm (should be the easiest from the list).

Comment: Wow, that's really good for a first question.  Unfortunately, I don't think most of us know the answer.  It might take a little bit before someone who knows sees this.  Sorry!  :(

Comment: *Kenneth Weber,* The accelerated integer GCD algorithm, *ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, volume 21, number 1, March 1995, pp. 111-122* (from the GNU MP project).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knuth explores the GCD at length in *The Art of Computer Programming*, Volume 2, Section 4.5.2. Knuth gives Algorithm E as the original method of Euclid, Algorithm A as the modern version of Euclid's algorithm, Algorithm B as the binary method and Algorithm L as Lehmer's method, as well as the extended Euclidean algorithm in Algorithm X. I describe (with code) the [original Euclidean algorithm](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/07/07/modular-arithmetic/), the [modern Euclidean algorithm](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/howto-posting-source-code/), the [binary algorithm](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/01/15/three-binary-algorithms/), and the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/07/07/modular-arithmetic/) at my blog.

[This paper](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/archive/sgcd.ps) gives a good description of several versions of Schönhage's algorithms, including code.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your answer user448810. That binary algorithm is perfect for me and freaking fast. I convert it to non recursive form to save memory and recursion calls.
Here is my C++ implementation for my `longnum` lib, added some rems for lines that are different from standard operators/functions

```cpp
longnum gcd(longnum x,longnum y)
    {
    x.sig=+1; x.integer(); // x=abs(int(x))
    y.sig=+1; y.integer(); // y=abs(int(y))
    longnum z; int x0,y0,sh=0;
    for (;;)
        {
        if (x.iszero()) { z=y; break; } // if (!x) ...
        if (y.iszero()) { z=x; break; } // if (!y) ...
        x0=x.a[_longnum_a1]&1; // x0=x&1
        y0=y.a[_longnum_a1]&1; // y0=y&1
        if ((!x0)&&(!y0)) { x>>=1; y>>=1; sh++; continue; }
        if (!x0) { x>>=1; continue; }
        if (!y0) { y>>=1; continue; }
        if (x<y) y-=x;
        else     x-=y;
        }
    return (z<<sh);
    }
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @vy32 `C++` and the `longnum` class is a fixed point bignum of mine so any nonstandard operation with it is commented